# Facebook (javascript SDK) create event with image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a hard time creating a facebook event with a picture.
I've tried many things found on stackoverflow, but most of them are using the php SDK.
Facebook documentation also doen't include an example on how to post a photo to the event.

The code I'm using is:

```
params = {'name': "some_name",
          'picture':"some_img_url_at_my_server",
          //or 'picture':"@some_img_url_at_my_server",
          //or '@picture':"@some_img_url_at_my_server",
          //or 'source':"some_img_url_at_my_server",
          //or 'source':"@some_img_url_at_my_server",
          //or 'picture':"some_img_path_at_my_server",
          //or 'picture':"@some_img_path_at_my_server",
          //or '@picture':"@some_img_path_at_my_server",
          //or 'source':"some_img_path_at_my_server",
          //or 'source':"@some_img_path_at_my_server",
          'start_time': "some_date"
};


FB.api('/me/events', 'post', params, function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        log(response.error);
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

The event gets created but no picture is shown.

I read somewhere that I have to url encode the picture data to the post I'm making but I don't know the way to do that in order to try it.

I fetching the data from a php page so, I could do that in the php page as well, but again, I don't know what I have to do exactly.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to do this in two steps:

1. Create the event and get its `id`.
2. `POST` to `/EVENT_ID/picture` with the picture content in the `source` parameter.

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#picture) for more details.

Comment: I'm getting the image from a database throught php and I'm posting the path to javascript in order to issue the FB.api post. How can I issue a multipart/form-data request?

Comment: Why not just make the post using the PHP SDK? I think if you're using an SDK that takes care of formatting everything for you.

Comment: cpliko, this is what I did, I was worried at first thinking that php and js sdk wouldn't work together. But I read on facebook documentation that they would work well together so I did it and it worked like a charm. It could event create the event along with a photo on the same request. :)